# How to make blender generate a 3D model by some text file?

Tags: 3d, blender

I am debugging a spatial 2D index and sometimes want to see existing index 3D (2d nodes and each has a level (like z-axis)). I would like to traverse my data structure (in a loop) and generate some sort of text file describing the structure. The resulting 3D model will consists of 3D boxed and will look like a tall building. What kind of such a text formats exists and supported by the blender?

So far my investigation lead me to blender python API...

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK to consider using OpenSceneGraph (OSG) instead of blender then you can consider using native OSG ascii file format or Collada (.dae) file format. Of you may have look at [fill list](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/UserGuides/Plugins).

Example of [OSG ascii file is here](https://github.com/verybigbadboy/osg-build/blob/master/osgBullet/data/offcube.osg) :

If you want to use only blender then start with simple STL files ([Blender supports them](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/STL)) and if does not satisfy your needs then find out other formats that can be imported and are easy enough for you to programmatically generate you content in that format.

Comment: Not limited with blender, will look at the OSG.